# Will Background App Refresh launch app to do refresh after it is killed by user?

Tags: ios

My app is using `Background App Refresh`. I'm not sure whether it will be launched by the system when the next refresh time comes if it is already killed by user from App Switcher.

Comment: Well, [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20) says the system can launch your app if it wants to: "launching the app directly into the background if needed".

Comment: I concede that this documentation is confusing. AFAIK, up until today i.e. using iOS SDK 7 a third party app on iOS can __NOT__ be launched in background under any circumstances. To clear the confusion about this particular case, see this response from Apple's engineer (link requires Apple developer login) https://devforums.apple.com/message/873265#873265

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to WWDC 2013 video 204 [What’s New with Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/):

If the user kills your app it will NOT be refreshed. If it is still in the multitasking tray (even in suspended state) it will be refreshed. The idea is that if user stops your application he/she doesn't need it to be refreshed.

Comment: Thanks. I think I found it: "Also, users will be able to swipe up to remove applications, and so just as before in iOS 6, that will stop the application from running but now in iOS 7, it will also stop that application from running in the background."

Comment: I think I do agree with @a-live comments in question as well. There are official/Apple statements over this feature which seems to me as _contradictory_. Search for words like "launch" and "swipe up" in this transcript of session 204 video http://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/204

Comment: On similar lines, you can refer page 14 and 33 of 133 from this session PDF. Page 33 provides API flow diagram over app being launched in background. It would be really helpful if someone can provide few facts (`NSLogs`) around this in iOS 7 from development/testing to clear this.

Comment: Once the app has been killed by swiping up in app switcher the background fetch handler will __NOT__ be called. See this reply from Apple (link requires apple developer login) - https://devforums.apple.com/message/873265#873265