# Is it possible for my iOS app to keep running code when a user kill my app?

Tags: ios, background, location

Is it possible for my iOS app to keep running code when a user kill my app? Now with latest iOS version (9.x), can we achieve this?

My app needs to send GPS locations to the server even a user kill this app.

Now my app keeps running in Background Mode. But not running after my app is killed.

Answer (score 1):

No.  If you could figure out how to keep things going after the user force quits/terminates your app, that app continuing to run after they are killed would certainly be considered a security risk (and performance hit) by Apple and wouldn't be allowed on the app store.

You might be thinking of [Background App Refresh](http://appinstructor.com/blog/2014/background-app-refresh-explained), but even if apps that utilize BAR are killed, [they don't refresh either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959106/will-background-app-refresh-launch-app-to-do-refresh-after-it-is-killed-by-user).

Comment: Thank you very much! What I try to do is sending GPS location of user even my app is killed. It  works in Background Mode only.  So it is impossible when app is killed right??